# Sending notifications client

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, webmethod

I want to send a notification (say a string) to subscribers(subscribers ip addresses are in a database on the server side) by calling another method. when ever I call that method the output becomes error-some.

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetGroupPath(string emailAddress, string password, string ipAddress)
{
    //SqlDataAdapter dbadapter = null;
    DataSet returnDS = new DataSet();
    string groupName = null;
    string groupPath = null;

    SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost;Database=server;User ID = admin;Password = password;Trusted_Connection=false;");

    dbconn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    string getGroupName = "select users.groupname from users where emailaddress = "+"'"+ emailAddress+"'"+ " and "+ "users.password = " + "'" +password+"'";
    cmd.CommandText = getGroupName;
    cmd.Connection = dbconn;
    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            groupName = reader["groupname"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        groupPath = "Invalied";
    }


    dbconn.Close();
    dbconn.Open();

    if (groupName != null)
    {
        string getPath = "select groups.grouppath from groups where groupname = " + "'" + groupName + "'";
        cmd.CommandText = getPath;
        cmd.Connection = dbconn;

        try
        {
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                groupPath = reader["grouppath"].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            groupPath = "Invalied";
        }
    }
    else
        groupPath = "Invalied";
    dbconn.Close();


    if (groupPath != "Invalied") 
    {
        dbconn.Open();
        string getPath = "update users set users.ipaddress = "+"'"+ipAddress+"'"+" where users.emailaddress = " + "'" + emailAddress + "'";
        cmd.CommandText = getPath;
        cmd.Connection = dbconn; 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbconn.Close();

    }

    NotifyUsers();
    //NotifyUsers nu = new NotifyUsers();
    //List<string> ipList = new List<string>();
    //ipList.Add("192.168.56.1");

    //nu.Notify();

    return groupPath;
}

private void NotifyUsers() 
{
    Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    byte[] ipb = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("255.255.255.255");
    IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress(ipb);

    IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 15000);
    string notification = "new_update";
    byte[] sendBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(notification);
    sock.SendTo(sendBuffer, endPoint);
    sock.Close();  
}
```

This is what has to be basically done. in the server side I have a listening thread and it gets notification when the server sends data( assume for now the database contains client ip address). then ever I call the web method it gives a error "invalid IPAddress" atline

```
byte[] ipb = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("255.255.255.255");
```

thank you :) since this is my first ever post please be kind enough to give me a better feedback too :)
 thaks

Comment: It's always a good idea to include the exception with questions like this - helps folks narrow down exactly what the issue is matey...

Comment: Please also think about SQL Injection Security issues with this code, think about using parameterised SQL or Stored Proc or ORM.

Comment: Sql injection is here true. i am just trying to make this work first.

Comment: ok,, I have figured out the problem. Does anyone knows what is the ip addres i should use in line
byte[] ipb = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("255.255.255.255");
I have used localhost(127.0.0.1) but no use. client is also running in the same machine. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code in notification, before that disable firewall setup...

```
try
{
    // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.

    // This example uses port 11000 on the local computer.
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName())

    Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

    IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress,15000);
    string notification = "new_update";
    byte[] sendBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(notification);
    sock.SendTo(sendBuffer, remoteEP );
    sock.Close();  
}
catch() {}
```

Hope this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that

```
byte[] ipb = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("255.255.255.255");
IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress(ipb);
```

can be reduced to

```
IPAddress.Broadcast
```

or, if you wanted to use another IP Address, you could also use .Parse()

```
var ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
```

**Update:**

Actually `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("255.255.255.255");` will give you a completely different result.

```
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("255.255.255.255");

// bytes returns something like
// new byte[] { 50, 53, 53, 46... }

// what you want is
var bytes = new byte[] { 255, 255, 255, 255 };
```